# why the last row and column of array is zero?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2013

I'm a beginner to C# and I want to write code for fuzzy max-min composition. I have used a 2D array for matrix. The problem I'm having is that the last row and column of array are zero. While the rest of the array elements are having right answer according to the fuzzy logic. The last row and column must have the same element as other elements of array.

Here is my code

```
public string[,] Max(string[,] matrix1, string[,] matrix2, int order)
    {
        string[,] fuzzy = new string[order, order];
        double max;
        double min;

        for (int i = 0; i < order; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < order; j++)
            {
                fuzzy[i, j] = "0.0000";

                for (int k = 0; k < order; k++)
                {
                    max = Convert.ToDouble(fuzzy[i, j]);
                    min = Math.Min(Convert.ToDouble(matrix1[i, k]), Convert.ToDouble(matrix2[k, j]));

                    //min = Math.Min(Convert.ToDouble(matrix1[i, j]), Convert.ToDouble(matrix2[i, j]));
                    max = Math.Max(min, min);
                    fuzzy[i, j] = Convert.ToString((String.Format("{0:0.0000}", max)));
                }
            }
        }
        return fuzzy;

    }
```

[image]

and here is the result

[image]

can any one help me why the last row and column is zero . .thanx.
the data is random data generated by using random class..

Comment: Please refrain from posting screenshots. Especially since they're screenshots of your *code*. Copy and pasting will help us answer your question.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with the statement `max = Math.Max(min, min);` which uses `min` *twice*, making it equivalent to doing `max = min;`. And if `min` equals zero... well, there you go.

Comment: What is the data in the arrays? Also, what do you mean by "the right answer according to fuzzy logic?" Can you show what your inputs are, and what you expect the output to be? You show what the actual output is but you never show what you expect it to be instead.

Comment: Also, please post your code and data as actual code so we can try it out ourselves rather than manually copying your code into our IDEs.

Comment: min is uses twice because the Math.Max function takes 2 arguments .. i got no other thing to write there as argument ..

Comment: @sarim So why not just assign min to max directly? Math.Max(min, min) will always just equal min.

Comment: @EJoshuaS .. no chnage.. same result again .. i tried it ..

Comment: @sarim I wouldn't expect that it would change anything - it *should* behave exactly the same as the old code, that's the point - the Math.Max call is completely unnecessary.

Comment: 0.1   0.3   0.5  0.7         0.9    0.1
 0.6  0.2  0.4  0.8                0.2  0.3



find the smallest (minimum)in row of matrix A with the column of matrix B
max(0.1^0.9, 0.3^0.2)
max(0.1,0.2)
then find  maximum from it
0.2
This is the(i,i) of the resulting matrix and so on the logic goes.. I have to implement it ....

Comment: do any one have any idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was really with the line max = Math.Max(min, min); , i have replaced it and got the correct output of fuzzy MAX_MIN operation on two matrices ..

the code

```
 //Fuzzy MAX-MIN Composition Code
    public string[,] Max(string[,] matrix1, string[,] matrix2, int order)
    {
        string[,] fuzzy = new string[order, order];
        double max = 0.0000;
        double min;

        for (int i = 0; i < order; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < order; j++)
            {
                fuzzy[i, j] = "0.0000";

                for (int k = 0; k < order; k++)
                {
                    max = Convert.ToDouble(fuzzy[i, j]);
                    min = Convert.ToDouble(fuzzy[i, j]);


                    min =Math.Min(Convert.ToDouble(matrix1[i, k]), Convert.ToDouble(matrix2[k, j]));
                    if(min > max)
                    {
                        fuzzy[i, j] = Convert.ToString((String.Format("{0:0.0000}", min)));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fuzzy[i, j] = Convert.ToString((String.Format("{0:0.0000}", max)));
                    }


                    //max = Math.Max(0.0000, min);   

                    //fuzzy[i, j] = Convert.ToString((String.Format("{0:0.0000}", min)));
                }
            }
        }
        return fuzzy;

    }
```